# KineticJS - parts of stage create pixel errors and refuse events

Tags: kineticjs

I'm currently writing chess using the most recent KineticJS.
Everything went well until I noticed, that there is a rectangle on stage, that seems to be buggy.
Before I go posting all the code I'd like to know if there have been similiar cases, where both events (click, mouseover) and tweens don't work in parts of the stage. Tweens cause pixel errors, where objects on the layer "duplicate" because the pixels aren't removed.

Could this be a kinetic-error or is it mine?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Please provide code so we can try to replicate the anomalies.

Comment: TBH, I've never come across anything like that in KineticJS so like markE said, please provide code or else we can't help you. It's not considered a good question to ask if anyone has encountered a problem before posting your code. If you have a specific question, just **ask** the specific question and provide all code that is relevant to reproducing the problem.